# How to highlight equal ignore case searchtext records in javascript?

Tags: javascript, search, text, highlight

If My data containing words like Krishna, krishna, KRISHNA then am entering search text as 'krish'. It will retriving all the three words. Up to here is fine but when i want to highlight the matching result, only the exact matching part of the string is highlating. How can i highlate the all matching string in the given data with out considering the case sensitive.

Below is the sample code which I Implemented:

```
var searchTxt='KRISH';

var actualTxt='Krish';

if(actualTxt.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTxt.toLowerCase()){
actualTxt = actualTxt.replaceAll(searchTxt,"<span style='font-weight: bold;background-color: yellow;'>"+searchTxt+"</span>");
}
```

Please any one help me in this.... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

html:

```
<input type="text"/>
<button>find</button>
<ul>
 <li>Krish</li>
 <li>Krish</li>
 <li>Krish</li>
 <li>LastOne</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
var li = $('ul li'),
input = $('input');

$('button').on('click', function(){
 var search = input.val(), regex;
 li.removeClass('highlight');
 if(search){
   regex = new RegExp(search, 'i')  
   li.filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).text().match(regex);
   }).addClass('highlight'); 
  }
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/wuyusugi/1/edit)